# combining two json to one in python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to convert multiple json objects to one using python.

example json1: its  a huge json with multiple key value pairs but a sample here as an example

```
[ 
   { 
      "key1":"value1",
      "key2":12563
   },
   { 
      "key1":"value1",
      "key2":12563
   },
   { 
       "key1":"value1",
       "key2":12563
   }
]
```

example json 2: its the same format with same key value pair for new set of data

```
  [ 
       { 
          "key1":"value1",
          "key2":12563
       },
       { 
          "key1":"value1",
          "key2":12563
       }
    ]
```

I want to combine them so as to get the final result as follow:

```
[ 
   { 
      "key1":"value1",
      "key2":12563
   },
   { 
      "key1":"value1",
      "key2":12563
   },
   { 
       "key1":"value1",
       "key2":12563
   },
   { 
       "key1":"value1",
       "key2":12563
   },
   { 
       "key1":"value1",
       "key2":12563
   }
]
```

I have tried using json merge library, tried to use json.dumps to serialie and tried and also tried using extend or append functions but not able to get the final result as I want.

Does anyone here have idea on this?
Tx.

Comment: _but not able to get the final result as I want_ If you show us what you tried, we can help.  Otherwise all we can say is "You must have done it wrong."

Answer (score 1):

Regex: `\s*\]\s*$`

- \s*: 0 or more whitespaces
- ]: match on ]
- $: match on end of string
- ^: match on beginning of string

Remove ending ] in first json string and [ in second json string and add a , in between to concatenate lists using regex and string replacement:

```
data1 = """[ 
   { 
      "key1":"value1",
      "key2":12563
   },
   { 
      "key1":"value1",
      "key2":12563
   },
   { 
       "key1":"value1",
       "key2":12563
   }
]"""
data2 = """
[ 
       { 
          "key1":"value1",
          "key2":12563
       },
       { 
          "key1":"value1",
          "key2":12563
       }
    ]"""

import json, re

result = re.sub(r"\s*\]\s*$",",",data1) + re.sub(r"^\s*\[\s*","",data2)

print(result)

#make sure it's valid json:
json.loads(result)
```

Deserialize.  Append the two lists.  Reserialize:

```
data1 = """[ 
   { 
      "key1":"value1",
      "key2":12563
   },
   { 
      "key1":"value1",
      "key2":12563
   },
   { 
       "key1":"value1",
       "key2":12563
   }
]"""
data2 = """
[ 
       { 
          "key1":"value1",
          "key2":12563
       },
       { 
          "key1":"value1",
          "key2":12563
       }
    ]"""

import json

data1 = json.loads(data1)
data2 = json.loads(data2)

print(json.dumps(data1+data2))
```

Comment: Thanks! In my case it was as easy as adding those two like below. Your (json.dumps(data1+data2)) helped me to get there.

result = data1 + data2